# fit a line with specified x and y axes in libre office calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spread sheet with two cloumns, x-axis and y-axis. How to a line using this information in libre office calc. data is like this:

```
confidence  credibility
0.9999981747    0.6892360526
0.9999974936    0.9310385438
0.9999964666    0.7190988966
0.9999963717    0.6902581837
0.9999960429    0.9970610436
0.9999955682    0.9705334336
0.9999954942    0.6756995859
0.9999928474    0.9272964967
0.9999911299    0.6978675182
0.9999910258    0.6879638681
```

How to get confidence on y-axis and credibility on x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `credibility` to column A and `confidence` to column B.  Then select the data and go to Insert -> Chart.  Chart Type is `XY (Scatter)`.

[image: chart]

Alternatively, keep `confidence` in column A.  In the `Data Series` step, select `X-Values` and change it to use column B.  Then select `Y-Values` and change it to use column A.

[image: data series]

**EDIT**:

To add a [trend line](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Trend_Lines), under `XY (Scatter)` set it to show points only.  Then select the points, right-click on the points and insert a trend line.

This video shows the steps involved: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4_GwWdUNqI

Comment: My data is in 10's of thousands, so When I used scatter plot, I can't decipher anything from that scatter. Taking it forward, for the scatter plot in XY-scatter, can I fit a curve. How good that would be, will that mis-lead the data information?